# Google Chrome Web Store Extension - Internationalization Problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-addons

I would like to internationalize my extension on the Google Chrome Web Store. More precisely: I would like to display a title, a description and a detailed description in the native language of each country I target.

To do this, I followed the official Google documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/i18n/

So I modified the manifest.json file by putting the following elements:

```
"name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "default_locale": "en",
```

In my "local" folder are contained all my messages.json files displaying a title and a description for each language. Here is an example of a messages.json file (in Spanish):

```
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "La Touche Musicale - Aprender a tocar el piano en línea"
  },
  "appDesc": {
    "message": "Aprende a tocar el piano fácilmente con las canciones que te gustan"
  }
}
```

I compressed my folder and imported the zip into the Chrome developer dashboard. The different languages appear well in the item edition and I can change the detailed description according to the language.

However, the name and description, filled in each of my messages.json files and not editable from the dashboard, remain in English. For example, if I choose the Spanish language, the title and description displayed are :

Title: "La Touche Musicale - Learn piano online
Description: "Learn piano easily with the songs you love".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGSyY.png)

This is the title and description of the language I selected by default (en) in the manifest.json file.

Why don't the title and description adapt to the selected language, as I defined in the messages.json files?

ATTACHED DOCUMENTS :

- Whole content of the manifest.json file :

  {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "**MSG_appName**",
  "description": "**MSG_appDesc**",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "version": "1.1",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "hello.html",
  "default_icon": {
  "16": "images/icon16.png",
  "32": "images/icon32.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png"
  }
  },
  "icons": {
  "16": "images/icon16.png",
  "32": "images/icon32.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png"
  }
  }
- Whole content of a messages.json file (es) [All messages.json files have exactly the same structure and content (except for the language translation)]:

  {
  "appName": {
  "message": "La Touche Musicale - Aprender a tocar el piano en línea"
  },
  "appDesc": {
  "message": "Aprende a tocar el piano fácilmente con las canciones que te gustan"
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Before the uploading in CWS you should test the extension in at least one of designed extension languages.
To do this you can set a language in your browser as "display Chrome in this language".

Comment: I can't test the internationalization of the extension in this way. Indeed, my extension does not have several languages in its code. The text elements that compose it are in English only. 

Where I would like to offer multiple languages is on the presentation page of my extension on the CWS. The problem is that I can't test the language displayed on the CWS presentation page by changing the default language of my Chrome browser (I tried with the "Show preview" function, it doesn't work, the page comes up in English while I had set the default language to Spanish).

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have not tried to put into practice what I suggested, otherwise you should have noticed that the description of the extension would be changed in the extension page (chrome://extensions/).
If this parameter changes, you are sure that it will also change in the CWS based on the user selected language.
If you don't believe it yet, you can try setting the extension in CWS as "unlisted".
When St. Thomas will has verified the miracle, he will hence be able to change the extension status to "public"